# Spy on a function inside a component method

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

For example I have

```
import React from 'react';
import { getProducts } from 'api/getProducts';

export class Example extends React.Component {
    state = {
        items: []
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchProducts();
    }

    fetchProducts = async () => {
        const { products: items } = this.state;
        if (items.length > 0) {
            return;  //TEST COVERAGE HERE MISSING
        }
        try {
            const { result } = await getProducts('/api/product/1');
            this.setState({ items: result });
        } catch (e) {
            // no-op
        }
    };

    render() {
        const { items } = this.state;
        return <div>{items}</div>;
    }
}
```

My test case is missing a coverage where it returns early if `items` already exists.

```
import React from 'react';
import { getProducts } from 'api/getProducts';
import { Example } from './Example';

jest.mock('api/getProducts');

describe('Example', () => {
    it('do not call getProducts if it already exists in state', async () => {
        const wrapper = mount(<Example />);
        const instance = wrapper.instance();
        instance.setState({
            items: [{ id: 1, name: 'kettle' }]
        });

        await instance.fetchProducts();

        //How to spy on getProducts and assert it hasn't been called?

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) method to mock `api/getProducts` module.

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { getProducts } from './api/getProducts';

export class Example extends React.Component {
  state: any = {
    items: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchProducts();
  }

  fetchProducts = async () => {
    // @ts-ignore
    const { items } = this.state;
    if (items.length > 0) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      const { result } = await getProducts('/api/product/1');
      this.setState({ items: result });
    } catch (e) {
      // no-op
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {items.map((item) => (
            <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`api/getProducts.ts`:

```js
export async function getProducts(url) {
  return { result: [] };
}
```

`index.spec.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Example } from './';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { getProducts } from './api/getProducts';

jest.mock('./api/getProducts.ts', () => {
  return {
    getProducts: jest.fn(),
  };
});

describe('Example', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should fetch products correctly', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Example></Example>);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();
    wrapper.setState({
      items: [{ id: 1, name: 'kettle' }],
    });
    await instance['fetchProducts']();
    expect(getProducts).toBeCalledWith('/api/product/1');
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59241777/index.spec.tsx
  Example
    ✓ should fetch products correctly (56ms)

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.tsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.273s, estimated 10s
```

Comment: @MichaelBlack If my answer helps you, please accept it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @ slideshowp2, I have removed the answer because I realised my main question was not answered. Even though your answer gets  100% coverage, why do you expect getProducts to be called with '/api/product/1'? If the items already exists fetchProducts should already return before caling getProducts. Shouldn't it be expected NOT to call? thanks in advance

Comment: We make a stub for `getProducts` method and also need to make sure it is be called with correct parameters which means we should make sure the code execution path is we expected. That's why we should expect `getProducts` to be called with `'/api/product/1'`